# Bring new email client window to front when clicking on mailto hyperlink from webpage

Tags: html

Is there a way to bring the new email window (outlook or default email client) to focus when clicking a mailto hyperlink from a webpage within a browser?

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Web Master</a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not explicitly, since that's up to the operating system and (in some cases) user-configured preferences. FWIW, the default behavior of most operating system / browser configurations does exactly what you want. So, if it doesn't work that way for a particular user, that's most likely because the user has specifically configured his or her system otherwise.